# Understand the layout of Google maps Android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to add a list in the front of map in Android. As given in the picture.
But I am unable to make the layout. I am confused that what google used for the `Show List` ttat expands upwards when someone click on it. Is the `map` is in a fragment? and `Show List` is also is in another fragment? or something else? Any clear view?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is showing inside a [Bottom Sheet](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html). It can be slide up from the bottom of the screen to reveal more content. Bottom Sheets are now supported in v23.2 of the support design library and onwards. There are two types of bottom sheets supported: [persistent](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-persistent-bottom-sheets) and [modal](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-modal-bottom-sheets). Persistent bottom sheets show in-app content, while modal sheets expose menus or simple dialogs.

There are lots of tutorials available. Here are some of them:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#bottom-sheets

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031